# How do I solve this integral $\int_{0}^{n} (1+x)^{x} \, dx $, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

An interesting integral, I don't know if it can be calculated, but we can try using a binomial series:

$$ (1+x)^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\begin{array}{l} x \\ k \end{array}\right) x^{k} $$

And then integrate.

Maple gave me $(n+1)^n-\frac{1}{n+1}$. But Wolfram breaks this "theory" already for $n=1$. Perhaps this is asymptotic behavior for large $n$.

Comment: The binomial series only works when $|x| < 1$ so it won't work for higher $n$

Comment: Look at this answer which almost the same as yours. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141347/finding-int-xxdx). Tym_

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash looks attractive, thanks.

Comment: Since $(1+x)^x<(1+x)^n$ for $0<x<n$, we have $\int_0^n (1+x)^x\,dx< \int_0^n (1+x)^n\,dx=(n+1)^n-\frac1{n+1}$. So your maple expression cannot be right. Perhaps you accidentally evaluated $\int_0^n (1+x)^{\color{red}n}\,dx$?

Comment: @Mike Earnest Yes, you are absolutely right, I checked it right now. My carelessness :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you could do is a series expansion
$$(1+x)^x=1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k\,\frac{a_k}{k!}\, x^k$$ where the first coefficients $a_k$ are
$$\{2,3,20,90,594,4200,34544,316008,3207240,35699400,432690312,\cdots\}$$ This is sequence [$A066166$](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2c%203%2c%2020%2c%2090%2c%20594%2c%204200%2c%2034544%2c%20316008%2c%203207240) in $OEIS$.

As you can see in the *formula* section, in year $2014$ Vaclav Kotesovec proposed, as an *approximation*,
$$a_k \sim k! \left(1-\frac{1}{k}-\frac{\log (k)+\gamma -1}{k^2}\right)$$

So, for the integral,
$$\int_0^n (1+x)^x\, dx=n+\sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k\frac {a_k}{(k+1)!}\, n^{k+1}$$ whjci will grow faster than an exponential.

Comment: I wonder how it is related to the linked ring Stanley’s children game sequence.

Comment: Note that this series does not converge when $|n|>1$.

Answer (score 2):

By L'Hôpital's rule,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{\int_0^n {(1 + x)^x dx} }}{{\frac{{(1 + n)^n }}{{\log (1 + n)}}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{(1 + n)^n }}{{(1 + n)^n \left( {1 + \frac{n}{{(1 + n)\log (1 + n)}} - \frac{1}{{(1 + n)\log ^2 (1 + n)}}} \right)}} = 1,
$$
which leads to the asymptotic formula
$$
\int_0^n {(1 + x)^x dx}  \sim \frac{{(1 + n)^n }}{{\log (1 + n)}}
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. With a more sophisticated application of L'Hôpital's rule, one can show the considerably more precise asymptotic formula
$$
\int_0^n {(1 + x)^x dx}=\frac{{(1 + n)^n }}{{\log (1 + n) + 1}}\left( {1 + \frac{{1 + o(1)}}{{(1 + n)\log (1 + n)}}} \right)
$$
as $n\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

As I have stated in a comment above, the binomial series only works when $|x|<1$. This means that for higher $n$ (nonzero in this case since $n \in \mathbb{N} $), the simplification to summation no longer works, so the integral gives an incorrect value.

Some resources on binomial series:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

https://brilliant.org/wiki/binomial-theorem-n-choose-k/

Answer (score 1):

Using [this graph with verifiable results](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rjktosd01f), we can solve the following. There may be a minor typo in here, but I tried as hard as I could to be accurate. I used basic [Binomial Theorem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj76Jm9x7vxAhWGFlkFHVNOCKoQ3KsCegQIARAJ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DSwaVN0epc0w&psig=AOvVaw2-vrhbTCjVhacPQo_yM67n&ust=1625011971761085), the [Maclaurin Series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) for exp(z), the [upper and lower incomplete gamma](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html) function. I skipped a bit using the first graph link and this [integration source](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x%5Ek+ln%5Em%28x%29+from+1+to+n%2B1) to simplify:

$$I(n)=\int_0^n (x+1)^xdx =\int_1^{n+1}x^{x-1}dx=\quad\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(-1)^{m-k}}{k!(m-k)!} (-(k+1))^{-(m+1)} \big(Γ(m+1)-Γ(m+1,-(k+1)\ln(n+1))\big)=\quad \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{(-1)^kγ(m,-k\ln(n))}{Γ(k)(m-k)!k^m}$$

This may be able to be simplified like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4112493/related-expressions-non-integral-forms-of-2%CF%80-sum-k-1%E2%88%9E-sum-k-1n-binom), but the alternating part is simpler than the answer’s. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: The second integral is from 1 to n+1.

Comment: @martycohen That is now fixed. Tell me if you have another suggestion.