# Solving the integral $\int_{-k}^{k} \frac{e^{-ax-bx^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I need to compute the definite integral.

> $$\int_{-k}^{k} \frac{e^{-ax-bx^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

Although the integral looks neat and fairly simple in form, I'm not able to evaluate it further. I tried evaluating it using integration by parts but without success. I also couldn't find the solution in the book, "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products" by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik.

Can anyone help me in solving this?

Thank you.

Comment: I couldn't prove it to you, but I'm almost positive this doesn't have a closed form. Take $(k,a,b) = (\frac{1}{2},1,0)$, and MatLab is unable to give an answer. When you mess with these $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and transcendental functions, it's rare you get a closed form. Would love to be proved wrong, though!

Comment: Basically this is *indefinite* integral (for $k$ being arbitrary).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never specified a closed form in your question, so here is an [exact form](https://web2.0calc.com/questions/what-is-exact-form) answer using the following: [integration source](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+x%5E%28m%2Bn%29%2Fsqrt%281-x%5E2%29+), [hypergeometric argument simplification](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/), [main simplification](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/01/0006/), [signum or sign function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), [**proof of series expansion**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mauokvvdk9), [an expansion of exp(y)](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-series-new/bc-10-14/v/taylor-series-at-0-maclaurin-for-e-to-the-x), [binomial theorem](https://medium.com/i-math/top-10-secrets-of-pascals-triangle-6012ba9c5e23),[incomplete beta function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/) and [hypergeometric function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html).

Using the Maclaurin series expansion for exp(y) and binomial theorem:
$$\mathrm{\int_{-k}^k \frac{e^{-bx^2-ax}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx= \int_{-k}^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-bx^2-ax)^n}{n!}dx= \int_{-k}^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \sum_{m=0}^n \binom nm b^ma^{n-m}x^{m+n}dx}$$

Integrating with the hypergeometric function seen above gives after a little simplification. The end is sped up with bound substitution already applied:

$$\mathrm{\int_{-k}^k \frac{e^{-bx^2-ax}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx= \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\sum_{m=0}^n \frac{b^ma^{n-m}}{m!(n-m)!} \int_{-k}^k \frac{x^{m+n}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\quad\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{b^ma^{n-m}k^{m+n+1}\left[(-1)^m+(-1)^n\right]\,_2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac{m+n+1}{2}, \frac{m+n+3}{2},k^2\right)}{m!(n-m)!(m+n+1)}= \quad \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{b^ma^{n-m}k^{m+n+1}\left[(-1)^m+(-1)^n\right]\left(\frac{m+n+1}{2|k|^{m+n+1}}B_{k^2}\left(\frac{m+n+1}{2},\frac12\right)\right)}{m!(n-m)!(m+n+1)}=  \quad\frac12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{b^ma^{n-m}sgn\left(k^{m+n+1}\right)\left[(-1)^m+(-1)^n\right]B_{k^2}\left(\frac{m+n+1}{2},\frac12\right)}{m!(n-m)!}}$$

Here is [**graphical proof**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wtgt7ioawh) of this result. Notice the inverse sine look to the graph.

Feel free to simplify this as the consecutive $(-1)^r$ terms look like they can be simplified. Go ahead and try this result if you like. The “proof of expansion link” takes a bit of time to load, so please be patient. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: That's quite an answer you got there.

Comment: This was really helpful. I will try to simplify the double summation in the last step even further. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JayanthJayakumar I have simplified the hypergeometric function. The alternating piece can be separated into two series. There may be a typo. What is this problem for?

Comment: @TymaGaidash, I tried simplifying the last step by first changing the order of summation using a double infinite sum identity since the double summation, as it stands, is difficult to evaluate analytically. Secondly, after separating into two series, I tried using some known identities for the Beta function to get a more compact form and then perform the said summation. However, I was not successful in both these attempts.

Comment: This problem is a small part of a bigger physics research problem where I need to compute the Wigner function corresponding to a state of light. By the way, do you have any more ideas/suggestions to simplify the double summation, just in case?

Comment: @JayanthJayakumar Please check the answer as there may he a typo, as I am human. You can split up the sum with the factored $[(-1)^m+(-1)^n]$. Here is a great example on a nice simplification:[Post with double sum simplification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4112493/related-expressions-non-integral-forms-of-2π-sum-k-1∞-sum-k-1n-binom). Tell me if this helps.

Comment: @TymaGaidash, I checked your answer by redoing it in a similar way and there was no typo. Further, I was able to split the sum as follows (from the last step). Please let me know if this correct. $= \sum_{s=0}^{\infty} \sum_{r=0}^{s} \frac{b^{2r} a^{2(s-r)}}{2r! (2(s-r))!} \text{sgn}(k^{2(r+s)+1}) B_{k^2} \big(\frac{2(r+s)+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\big) - \sum_{s=0}^{\infty} \sum_{r=0}^{s} \frac{b^{2r+1} a^{2(s-r)}}{(2r+1)! (2(s-r))!} \text{sgn}(k^{2(r+s)+3}) B_{k^2} \big(\frac{2(r+s)+3}{2},\frac{1}{2}\big)$.

Comment: @JayanthJayakumar  Whoops, the graph should be the the square root part in the bottom. This actually looks correct, just do the (2r)! and not 2r!. You are correct! [**New graph**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ftzg7c2ffd). Notice how the integral and your result have the same graph.

Comment: @JayanthJayakumar [_Here_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4205765/on-a-better-solution-for-large-int-xx-fracdx-sqrt-1-x2-ebx2ax) are results for a simplified answer.

Comment: @RounakSarkar It can be simplified with a special function in [*this edited version*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4205765/on-a-better-solution-for-large-int-xx-fracdx-sqrt-1-x2-ebx2ax).

Comment: @TymaGaidash. I love how you saw my comment like 2 months later. It's ok

Comment: @RounakSarkar I guess we met before. I also saw your $\int \text{Si}^n(x) dx$ post.

Comment: @TymaGaidash. I am not sure what do you mean by 'we have met before'. Yeah we have talked here in this site before.